# Trigger or Change Notification on SQL Server view

Tags: t-sql, view, triggers

We have following scenario:

```
create table User {Id bigint, UserName nvarchar(50), GroupId bigint}; 
create table Group {Id bigint, GroupName nvarchar(50)}; 
create view UserView as 
    SELECT u.Id, u.UserName, g.GroupName 
    from User u 
          inner join Group g on u.GroupId = g.Id
```

Now I'd like to create one trigger on the view which is fired if the User table is updated or/and if the group table is updated.

Is this possible somehow using T-SQL?

Using INSTEAD OF triggers doesn't work because they are fired only if you perform updates directly to the view.

Thanks.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve exactly please?

Comment: I want to execute T-SQL code if view data changes. 
Like a query notification to "select * from view" only at T-SQL level (if query notifications were possible on views...)

Answer (score 3):

No, this is not possible. You'll have to define your triggers on the tables that are involved in the view in order to process changes.